# How to get all lists a user belongs to using Mailchimp API?

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am looking through the [Mailchimp API documentation](http://developer.mailchimp.com/) but cannot seem to find an api call that will take a user_id and return the list of newsletter_ids to which they are subscribed.

Does anyone know of any method available for this purpose?